# How to create framework from Xcode 4 project?

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4, chdatastructures

I want to use **CHDataStructures** as framework: https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures. However there is no binary of the project.

So I assume I have to build the .a file myself using xcode. How do I do that in xcode 4? I read the documentation but it is very confusing...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check out the README.html file in the project?  Seems pretty straight forward to build and then invoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we'll grab the CHDataStructures project:

```
git clone https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures.git
```

Next, open the relevant CHDataStructures xcode project

```
open CHDataStructures-iOS.xcodeproj
```

I'll assume you're building for iOS from here on out (and mention what will be different for a mac app). Once xcode is up and running, ensure that `iOS Static Library` is selected in the `scheme` drop-down, and then hit `run`. Once done, xcode has built the binary for you, and you'll be able to find it in `Products` in the navigator. Open the required binary (for iOS it's the compiled `.a` binary, for Mac it's the `.framework` collection).

Finally (expanding on the documentation):

- Open the Xcode project for your iOS app.
- Add `libCHDataStructures.a` and the library header files (all the `.h` header files in the `framework` subdirectory from the xcode project above) to your project by dragging them to the "Groups & Files" pane of your xcode project.
- In the project navigator, select your project
- Select your target
- Select the 'Build Phases' tab
- Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
- Click the '+' button
- drag libCHDataStructures.a into the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase.
- Add #import "CHDataStructures.h" where necessary in your code.

Comment: "ensure that iOS Static Library is selected in the scheme drop-down, and then hit run." -- What scheme drop-down?  I don't see one.