# Swift and AFNetworking integration

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, swift, afnetworking-2, ios8

Now as **swift** is the new language to develop iOS apps.

How can we integrate with the **AFNetworking** or
using **NSURLSession** will be a better option ???

Please help me out..

Comment: AFNetworking for Swift is now called AlamoFire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: ^ AlamoFire is still missing some functionality expected by AFN users, such as setImageWithURL:

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to add AFNetworking to your swift project

In Build Settings -> Defines Module set to Yes

In Build Settings -> Swift compiler -> Objective-C bridging file set the name of bridging file 'ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h' for example

In ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h write:

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

Comment: For these who search in settings - key is 'Defines Module' (under Packaging)

Comment: One trick: If you already add ObjC file and accept that it to create Bridging file, but delete it and try do this again, XCode don't ask if you want to create it anymore. Restart the XCode and voilá.

Comment: In "Objective-C bridging file", set the name to: "ProjectName/bridge.h"

Comment: I had a Swift project with a bridge header for Parse SDK.  Now I added AFNetworking and added AFNetworking.h to the birding header.  Restarted Xcode but it can't find AFHTTPClient, AFJSONRequestOperations and others.

Comment: This is probably an ignorant question, but how exactly should I add AFNetworking. It does not have a sperate project with its own build settings, but only loose Objective-C files. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 12):

> Any Objective-C framework (or C library) that’s accessible as a module
>   can be imported directly into Swift. This includes all of the
>   Objective-C system frameworks—such as Foundation, UIKit, and
>   SpriteKit—as well as common C libraries supplied with the system. For
>   example, to import Foundation, simply add this import statement to the
>   top of the Swift file you’re working in:

you just need to import them into your project and create bridging header. you can find detailed explanation [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)