# An issue with Swift + Objective C framework on XCode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode9.4

I have some unique case when `Objective C` framework is integrated in a `Swift` framework. Everything seems to be fine when I make build. Also, when I use this new framework in the project that is written in `Objective C` I have no issues.

But when I use it in the project written in `Swift 4.1`, after my import statement, I get an error message:

> module is not found "the name of Obj C framework"*

When I used `Xcode 9.2` back in the days everything worked fine. So, this issue  appeared only after `Xcode 9.4`.

I believe there's something that could be changed in a build settings maybe, but, unfortunately, I don't have enough experience to find this out. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Before import newly added any framework to your class file first build a code then import it.

Comment: Hi, Are you getting any solution for that issue? I am facing same issue in my application too.

Comment: @Hindu, I had to separate 2 frameworks and use them in my project. Unfortunately, this is not a solution that I wanted to do....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found the issue and resolve it.

Comment: @Hindu, could you please share how you made that work? As I’m not happy enough of using 2 frameworks separately.

Answer (score 1):

I found a link [Swift and AFNetworking integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120402/swift-and-afnetworking-integration) to integrate the Obj c framework in Swift Project . I hope it would work for you. Plus Check your header file path and framework path in your project.

Comment: I'm afraid this post is not relevant as I have another case. I have Swift framework (with objective c framework inside) that should be used in a Swift project.